Flutter App generates dynamic JWTs. Any way to extract the secret?
I am analyzing an android app that sends http requests with JWTs containing a timestamp in the payload. So they have to be signed in the app somehow. This is the header and payload
 {"alg":"HS256","typ":"JWT"}.{"auth_token":"d871be6fffbb1b6318119c1be4ea7f44c3be08119","id":81,"issuedTime":1730122121.013}


The secret has to be stored inside the app because the JWTs are already sent in the very first request after installing the app.
I have set up Frida and burp suite to inspect the traffic. Is there any way to analyze the app in such a way that I can find the signing method and log its arguments (one of them being the secret)?

I would recommend frida-trace for hooking bunches of Java/native methods. It will generate hooking code in the current directory you can then manually change if you have identified an interesting function. On Java you can throw and catch manually created Exceptions to see the stack trace.

@Robert I was able to do it using radare2 to decompile the libapp.so and then blutter to dump the dart snapshot
